# How do I update Mass Edit/Update app to reference a different domain?

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on

We recently implemented a vanity URL (MyDomain) and  SAML SSO (`Okta`) and now the `Mass Edit` and `Mass Update` apps don't work.  When logged in to Salesforce, if I try to launch either from an `Account` or `Opportunity` view I am sent out to `Okta` which authenticates me and then takes me back into SF to my home page. I'm not a developer, but with the right instructions can probably update the necessary `Visualforce Pages` used by `Mass Edit` an `Mass Update`.

If I bypass my SSO then both Edit and Update work...

Comment: I am just guessing but the problem could be with the SSO configuration. Either in Salesforce or your Identity provider. I think somewhere in the configurations you would have specified the domain, and since VF pages exist on different domains than your regular SF pages, it is asking you to relogin.

Comment: Reposting this since I was never able to figure it out and it is still a problem  Thanks AslamK for your reply... I understand your suggestion but don't really know specifically where to look.